# how to call an application from another application by validating credentials

Tags: asp.net, session

i have 2 web applications 1) webgrants 2)Reports this is to view reports

We provide a link to Reports app in webgrants.Once the users logs into Webgrants and clicks on the Reports link he will be redirected to Home page in reports app.

The Reports app can be accessed directly and from webgrants app, so my question is how do we know whether the user is coming from webgrants or accessing directly.

I am thinking of using session when he comes from webgrants i wants to check if session exists if it is null redirect to login page else to home page ... is this is good approach or any best way ????????

Comment: You can check the http referrer.

Comment: how can i use this in my app..i need some more explanation please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using forms authentication and setting it to work across apps. that way a user logged in on one app will be also logged in on the other. You can then use roles authorization to work out if they are allowed to do that.

Simon

Comment: i didn't understand your point..can i use session here this way when they click the link it will redirects to reports,in this pageload i want to check if session is null if yes i will direct to login page or else to home page

Comment: session is specific to each app. there is a built in mechanism with forms authentication to allow you to pass a logged-in identity between apps.

Comment: session will also never be null (unless you switch sessions off altogether) as soon as a user uses your app, they've got a session.